# how to append a integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this array:

```
listPatients =   [[  "Johnson",   "Fred", "N", "2763 Filibuster Drive",  "Lakeland", "FL", "37643", "Q", "05/27/1935", "164-55-0726", "N"]] \
+                [[ "Williams",  "Betty", "L",    "701 Collage Avenue",   "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "F", "11/27/1971", "948-44-1038", "Y"]] \
+                [[     "Ling", "Hector", "X",     "1500 Raceway Lane",     "Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "10/17/2003", "193-74-0274", "Y"]] \
+                [[    "Albin",   "Ross", "L",      "207 Daisy Avenue",  "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "12/08/1990", "458-57-2867", "N"]] \
+                [[ "Anderson",  "Jason", "O",       "1527 Lewis Road",     "Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "11/25/1991", "093-50-1093", "Y"]] \
+                [[     "Baca",  "Edwin", "L",       "25 Hunters Lane",  "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "10/30/1992", "159-56-9731", "Y"]] \
+                [[   "Birner", "Dalton", "M",     "851 Applebe Court",   "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "M", "09/22/1993", "695-21-2340", "Y"]] \
+                [["Dominguez", "Javier", "B",   "1410 Waterford Blvd",   "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "M", "08/04/1994", "753-66-6482", "N"]] \
+                [[   "Aimino", "Nicolo", "S",      "2379 Runners Way",  "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "07/11/1995", "852-73-4196", "Y"]] \
+                [["Armstrong","Addison", "T",    "46 Hawthorne Drive",  "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "06/18/1996", "648-81-1456", "Y"]] \
+                [[    "Beard",    "Ian", "J",  "1814 Constitution Ct",   "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "M", "05/28/1997", "879-61-1829", "N"]] \
+                [[ "Calderon",  "Yamil", "C",         "345 Cigar Row",     "Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "04/07/1998", "123-87-6431", "Y"]] \
+                [[   "Carter", "Thomas", "P",       "896 Pine Avenue",        "Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "03/12/1999", "248-65-3197", "Y"]] \
+                [[  "Chaname",  "Bryan", "D",    "24 Blue Belt Drive",           "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "02/23/2000", "741-85-9632", "Y"]] \
+                [[   "Chaney", "Chaney", "Z",    "2589 College Court",     
"Orlando", "FL", "31234", "M", "01/15/2001", "963-25-7418", "Y"]]
```

I want to append the age; which is a calulation after taking the birthyear (index(array(element[7]))) and subtracting it from the year 2015:

```
for patients in range(len(listPatients)):
    YOB=listPatients[patients][8][6]+listPatients[patients][8][7]
    +listPatients[patients][8][8]+listPatients[patients][8][9]
age= currentYear-int(YOB)
story4=patients.append(age)
```

The output says I can't append a integer. What can I do?

Comment: Can you add the full traceback?

Comment: I think it says `'int' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: patients is not a list in this case

Comment: forget about range just iterate over `listPatients` then patients will actually be a list

Comment: I hope this isn't real patient data.

Comment: @user5402 some of those addresses don't exist so it's probably not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to appent to a listPatients element, not the range of it:

```
for patients in range(len(listPatients)):
    YOB=listPatients[patients][8][6]+listPatients[patients][8][7]+listPatients[patients][8][8]+listPatients[patients][8][9]
    age= currentYear-int(YOB)
    story4=listPatients[patients].append(age)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I ran this code myself on the OPs data and **it works perfectly**. Whoever downvoted, care to explain?

Comment: I'd really like the downvoter to explain. This is the simplest change you can make to the code to make it work. Maximum result with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `patients` is the index in the list of list, not the sublist itself, i.e. with `patients.append(age)` you are trying to append to a number! Instead, try iterating over the `listPatients` itself. Also, you can use the slice `[6:]` instead of concatenating all those individual characters of the year, or use `patients[8].split('/')[2]` to get the year.

```
for patients in listPatients:
    YOB = patients[8][6:] # or patients[8].split('/')[2]
    age = currentYear - int(YOB)
    patients.append(age)
```

Also, `append` does not return anything, so whatever `story4` is supposed to be, it will always be `None`.

Finally, you can write your multi-line list of lists like this:

```
listPatients =   [[  "Johnson",  ... stuff ..., "164-55-0726", "N"],
                  ... many more lines ...
                  [   "Chaney",  ... stuff ..., "963-25-7418", "Y"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use the `range` for iterating here.

```
for patient in listPatients:
    YOB=patient[8][-4:]
    age= currentYear-int(YOB)
    patient.append(age)
    story4=age
```

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet, `patients` *is* an `int`, which has no `append` method.

```
>>> range(len(['x','y','z']))
[0, 1, 2]
```

Each item in the range iterator will be an integer.

Comment: so should I string (patients)? @C.B.

Comment: @JoshuaPilkin  what is `story4` supposed to be?

Comment: story4's output will be my patient's age. @C.B.